# Does the pseudo-arc contain Erdős space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory, continuum-theory

The [pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) is the unique hereditarily indecomposable chainable continuum.

The [Lelek fan](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Epyrih/e/e2001v1/c/ect/node87.html) is the unique compact, connected subset of the Cantor fan (the cone over the Cantor set) with a dense endpoint set. The Lelek fan is a decomposable continuum and thus does not embed into the pseudo-arc.

**Question.** Does the set $E(L)$ of endpoints of the Lelek fan embed into the pseudo-arc?

This is equivalent to asking whether the pseudo-arc contains [Erdos space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_space) $\mathfrak E$, as each of $E(L)$ and $\mathfrak E$ contains the other.

Comment: The pseudoarc $P$ contains a topological copy of $C\times P$, where $C$ is the Cantor set: (a) $P$ is not Suslinean, (b) any nondegenerate subcontinuum of $P$ is homeomorphic to $P$, (c) by a result of van Douwen 1993 $P$ contains a copy of $C\times P$. Hence your question is equivalent to: Does $C\times P$ contains the Erdös space? I suspect that this is true, since a similar process as in the construction of Erdös space inside $C\times [0,1]$ can be followed. Of course, the details need to be checked (e.g. using a topological characterization of Erdös space).

Comment: Perhaps a Cantor-set-valued function can be defined from $C$ into $P$, using the arclength function on the Lelek fan, so that the graph (as a subspace of $C\times P$) is homeomorphic to $C\times E(L)$, which is homeomorphic to $E(L)$.